# How to identify a disabled switch in android

Tags: android

I am developing an android project where I am struck in a case, where I have to identify (ie.. to get some information about the 'disabled switch') so that I can use that particular disabled switch's information to change the database through PHP query. Please let me know your valuable suggestions.
Here is my code where I declared the switch -

```
mySwitch = new Switch[len];
flag = new int[len]; 
pnr = new String[len]; 
id = 0; 
for( j = 0; j < len; j++ ) { 
   newlist = passenger[j].split("#"); 
   pnr[j] = newlist[0]; 
   hrow = new TableRow(this); //create row for each passenger     
   hrow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
   hrow.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 3);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code where the switch was defined?

Comment: @Sagnik You should edit the question and put that code there, instead of posting unformatted code into a comment.

Comment: I just want to know sir, how to detect the switch.setClickable(false) elements,ie..the elements which were stored in the database because of switch.setClickable(false). How can we detect them ?

Comment: Why do you use `setClickable`? Don't you want to use `setOnCheckedChangeListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your looking for is `isClickable()` (according to your comment)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isClickable()